# Example of Foundation 4 collapsing main navigation (aka drawer) implemented in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

We've got flow with Twitter Bootstrap but we love the way Foundation 4 collapses main navigation on mobile. Has anyone done this for Bootstrap 3 yet? We don't want to jump frameworks for one feature.

[image: Foundation 4 mobile navigation]

This side navigation seems more consistent with trends in native app navigation than the Bootstrap hamburger dropdown.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another demonstration that may work for you:
http://zombiehippie.github.io/Side-drawer/

Comment: Pretty slick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a basic solution I can build on here:

http://bootply.com/88026

It persists the header, but that can be adjusted.